# Handle AsyncTask in Class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask Class to handle images that are coming from the server to display it in the ImageView
 I have one Next button in my code to call the next image using following code:

```
private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if (imgque != null) {
            imgSelectedQue.setImageDrawable(imgque);
            if (getActivity() != null) {
                adjustResourceEnvelope();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        imgque = null;
        imgSelectedQue.setImageDrawable(null);
        imgSelectedQue.requestLayout();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = (InputStream) new URL(Constants.PLAYER_SERVICE_BASE_URL + "/playerservice"
                    + imageurl).getContent();
            imgque = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            imgque = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

Now the issue is that if I click the next button **REPEATEDLY** then it call the AsyncTask that many times and ImageView displaying all the images like "Slide-Show" because all the url images are in queue.
Is there any way to display only last AsyncTask call image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the Solution for this.
If anyone facing the same issue.
I Added new lines

```
if (loadimage != null)
 {
   loadimage.cancel(true);
   loadimage = null;
}

loadimage.cancel(true) will stop the AsyncTask if it is already Running
```

then execute the AsycTask()

```
loadimage = new LoadImage();
loadimage.execute();
```

In this way i am able to call only last AsyncTask that what I required.

Comment: It is not efficient, also note that the behaviour of cancel call is vary case by case, it is not guaranteed to be success all the time, check out the API for yourself.

Comment: ok @yorkw it is worked for me... if you have any suggestion then please tell me.

Comment: The common strategy is to use AsyncTask.getStatus(). when button clicked, do not start another one iff there is one currently running.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

[1] When you call `LoadImage AsyncTask` on click of `NEXT` button `disable` NEXT button.

[2] On `onPreExecute()` method of your `LoadImage AsyncTask` `enable` your `NEXT` button again.

OR,

You can achieve such things with use of simple `FLAG` also. By setting it as true and false.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: My client doesnt want to disable the next button because if internet is slow it will keep him idle.

Comment: Then you should go with setting flag which will allow you to add next job in queue only if current job is finished.

Comment: sure. Let me know if you need any help from me.

Comment: Hey @Pratik Sharma I found one solution. just cancel your previous AsyncTask using loadimage.cancel(true) and make it null before using that again. thank you for your response.

Comment: @BaZinga That's great. Hope my efforts are helpful to you somehow. :)